# Node app application error

Tags: node.js, api, heroku, ecmascript-6

I am new to node js i built a small api and am unable to use on heroku because am using es6 here is what my log looks like [LOG](http://pastebin.com/3LRnc94C) and here is what my package.json looks like 
[Package.json](http://pastebin.com/jaye06G3)

Answer (score 0):

The error in the log tells you:

```
2016-12-05T13:05:06.481722+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: babel: not found
```

Looking at your package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.7.1"
  }
```

There is, in fact, no babel listed. Neither is there pm2 listed (and your npm start command looks for it).

By default, heroku only installs dependencies, not devDependencies.  You could [tell them to install that](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#devdependencies), but I'd not recommend it as you probably will have things there that aren't appropriate.  Instead, include the things that you need as dependencies.

Comment: So i can install babel and pms as dependencies instead?

Comment: Dude, read your error log and ask another question once you've at least attempted to solve it.  `2016-12-05T18:41:35.885220+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "/app"`

Comment: Adding to that, if it's only ES6 you're using, make sure you Node version is on 6.x or higher and you don't need to use Babel at all.